# Media player separating controls in different files and extending base classes like button, playlist

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, media

I want to create a player that has everything in one window (buttons: play, stop, next, playlist as listbox with buttons for add,sort files in playlist).

i want to separate these classes in different files and make it extend main classes. If i create class MyButton that extends BUtton class, how can i instantiate buttons in xaml, not defining positions, margins, styling in code behind?

I want playlist to be separate class that extends ListBox and implements IObservable, but if i define it in another file, i cannot access it from mainwindow.